# symfony 4 form translate variable in twig include

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am currently trying to translate a string in Symfony/Twig inside an include Statement for a twig Template.
This is the non-translated Code is use for it currenty:

```php
{{ include('@BluelineUser/user/_form.html.twig', {
    'back_link': path('user_index'),
    'title' : 'Edit User: ' ~ user.username,
    'button_caption': 'Save'
}) }}
```

And in my form I output it like this:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <h1>{{ title|trans }}</h1>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Now if I use the include with a diffrent title (without a variable in it) it works fine.

Adding this to my translation file just doesn't pick up the 'Edit User: '

```
<trans-unit id="edit.name2">
    <source>Edit User: </source>
    <target>Benutzer bearbeiten: </target>
</trans-unit>
```

Any idea on how to get they 'Edit User: ' in the title translated? I think it's breaking because of the variable.
So far couldn't find any example on how to get this working in an include statement.

Comment: I would give this a try `{{ (title)|trans }}`

Comment: Tried both but that didn't work. Is it possible that this is due to the string getting set as something like 'Edit User: admin1@mail.com' and the translation is thus not recognized? Adding the 'Edit User: admin1@mail.com' as string to my xlif triggers the translate. This can't be the solution tho. Has to work for all usernames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to translate it before like this:

```
{{ include('@BluelineUser/user/_form.html.twig', {
    'back_link': path('user_index'),
    'title' : ('Edit User: '|trans) ~ user.username,
    'button_caption': 'Save'
}) }}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm - wasn't aware I was able to add pipes like this